# I cannot connect to the extensions marketplace in vscode ver: 1.70.2 . Also I cannot install .vsix in that version

Tags: visual-studio-code

I cannot connect to the extensions marketplace in vscode -ver.: 1.70.2 . Also I cannot install .vsix in that version. Help me. I am using 32 bit windows 7.
I also tried using previous versions of vscode but that didn't work too.
Now you might be wondering why I am not using the latest version. The reason is my computer specifications.
VS Code latest versions no longer support Windows 7.

My PC specs are :

WINDOWS 7 ULTIMATE
DUAL CORE PENTIUM PROCESSOR (32-BIT)
RAM - 2GB , ROM - 128 GB SSD & 256 GB HDD

I tried changing proxy settings ( by watching youtube tutorials) & also edited settings.json file but nothing really works for me. Please help me out.

Comment: "_Also I cannot install .vsix in that version_" how are you trying to do that? Do you get any error messages? And out of curiosity, why are you using VS Code 1.70? The latest version is 1.77.

Comment: I am running a Windows 7 (32-bit system). & VS Code's latest versions no longer support Windows 7. That's why I am using older versions.

Comment: & yes I also got an error message telling me that " .VSIX Extension is not compatible with your system" or " XHR Failed" etc. stuff like that.

Comment: Please always [edit] clarifications into your question post instead of hiding them in the comments! Comments are for _soliciting_ clarifications- not for providing them. Give full and exact error messages and how to reproduce them.